# Lyx Modify Document Class

Tags: lyx

I have spent the last few hours trying to modify article.cls to conform to my professor's paper requirements (title above abstract, page numbers don't start until the second page of the introduction), but this LaTex code is wildly unfamiliar to me, and I don't see how I can accomplish what I need to.

Can someone direct me towards a reference/tutorial/documentation of creating and modifying LaTex document classes for Lyx?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to modify the article class if you're only after those two changes. And I haven't ever seen the title being posted below the abstract if you composed it above the abstract.

Since you're using Lyx I'd point you to the [Lyx wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/)

Theres some really good documentation there including:
[Starting Numbering on a different page](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Numbering#startpage)

Also remember that you can try inserting raw tex code (ctrl-L if I remember right) in lyx, although it can have mixed results. Simple code tends to work fine. If you are recommended to change the preamble, lyx puts that in Document-Settings-Latex Preamble.

I also point most tex beginners to the [Latex Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) since it is a very nice reference.

Comment: I do not want to have to insert TeX code in my document every time I write a paper, mainly because that defeats the purpose of using Lyx in my case (if formatting is going to be this complicated, may as well use MS Word). But where, in the latex wikibook, is there a section on modifying/creating document classes?

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample input, it's a bit hard to be confident of suggestions, but I believe that if you use `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the front page, it'll suppress the page numbers on the first page.

Also, if you place the `\title{}` above the `\begin{abstract}`, I believe it'll output that way in the final rendering.

If these combined don't do what you need, try `texdoc fancyhdr` for details on a package that -- while being vastly overkill -- can probably be configured to do what you need.